# Daily notifcations Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, ios10

I'm trying to figure out how to send a notification once a day at a specific time (say 8am) without user input and using the new `UNMutableNotificationContent` instead of the deprecated `UILocalNotification` and not using user input to trigger it but rather a time. All of explanations If found are old and don't include ios 10 and swift 3.

What I have so far.

Authorized Notifications in ViewController.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in
        })
    }
```

Notification.swift

```
let localNotification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
//    localNotification.fireDate = dateFire
    localNotification.title = "title"
    localNotification.body = "body"
    localNotification.badge = 1
    localNotification.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
```

I know I have to set a trigger and request among other things but im not sure exactly how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check out this tutorial -  [Hacking with swift Notification center](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/21/2/scheduling-notifications-unusernotificationcenter-and-unnotificationrequest)

What you need is the date components part.

```
 func scheduleLocal() {
      let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    let localNotification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    localNotification.title = "title"
    localNotification.body = "body"
    localNotification.badge = 1
    localNotification.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.hour = 10
        dateComponents.minute = 30
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: localNotification, trigger: trigger)
        center.add(request)
    }
```

Check out the tutorial for more. It is written in swift 3 iOS 10. [Here's github repo](https://github.com/twostraws/HackingWithSwift/tree/master/project21) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

First step:

```
import UserNotifications
```

And to judgement whether the user allows notification

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
granted, error in
    if granted {
        // determine whether the user allows notification
    }
}
```

Second step:

Create notification

```
// 1. create notification's content
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Time Interval Notification"
content.body = "My first notification"

// 2. create trigger
//custom your time in here
var components = DateComponents.init()
components.hour = 8
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)

// 3. send request identifier
let requestIdentifier = "com.xxx.usernotification.myFirstNotification"

// 4. create send request
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

// add request to send center
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
    if error == nil {
        print("Time Interval Notification scheduled: \(requestIdentifier)")
    }
}
```

You can find more information at [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications)