# Open app automatically by triggering some event like push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm building an app in Swift in which I want to open the app automatically even when the app is closed by triggering some activity. I have implemented it in android using push notification in which the app opens automatically on receiving push notification. But can't figure it out in IOS.

Comment: you can look this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787351/daily-notifcations-swift-3/41788417#41788417),hope help you!

Comment: You can't open an app on iOS without user interaction. You can show a local notification and if the user taps it then your app will be opened.

Comment: Use pushkit and local notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that on iOS. Only the user can open the app.

The only thing you can do is get the app to open in the background, to do some processing, but the user has to act upon your notification to open the app.

Comment: I get it .its not possible with push notification .but is there some other way that the user knows that he has to open the application like calling functionality in whatsapp.

Comment: You can use I think CallKit, if your app is actually a video or audio chat in real time. Otherwise the Apple review will reject the app.